# Изменить фон у нескольких блоков

Tags: java, android

У меня есть n блоков RelativeLayout. Каким образом всем им изменить фон программно?

---

Есть RelativeLayout созданные программно. Их разное количество, от 3 до 10-ти. По клику нужно поменять background у всех созданных RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#9A9595"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Текст"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#9A9595"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Текст"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/idN"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#9A9595"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Текст"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: уточните вопрос пожалуйста, так сложно помочь без какого-либо кода и более развернутого вопроса

Comment: <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#9A9595"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Текст"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

Comment: вообще ничего не понятно, дополните вопрос всей необходимой информацией, тут не битва экстрасенсов :( используя предоставленную информацию помочь сложно будет, добавьте информацию в вопрос чтобы он был понятен любому кроме вас :)

Comment: нажмите [edit] чтобы отредактировать вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Берете родителя этих RelativeLayout(s) и проходите в цикле

```
RelativeLayout rl_root = findViewById( R.id.root ); // здесь ваш, тип может быть другой
for( int i = 0; i < rl_root.getChildCount(); i++ ){
    View v = rl_root.getChildAt( i );
    v.setBackgroundColor( Color.CYAN );
}
```